# Output of scipy's wavfile.read function

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, wav, audio-processing

I tried using the scipy.io.wavfile.read function the get the soundpressure of a soundtrack and get, as indicated in the doc two outputs : the sampling rate and a data numpy array. So far so good.

My problem is that the output array is (Nx2) dimensional and I don't know what the two dimensions represents. I was expecting to get a (Nx1) dimensional array with the total number of samples.

I have looked online and didn't find anything, and even after converting the audio signal to mono, I still get a Nx2 array so I don't think these are the left and right channel (but I could be wrong).

running the following code :

```
scipy.io.wavfile.read(path+"slow_jazz.wav")
```

gives the following output :

```
(44100, array([[-1.37977577e-06,  8.62224842e-05],
   [ 1.10934685e-04, -1.24923863e-05],
   [ 3.23722816e-05,  6.47113484e-05],
   ...,
   [ 2.37652988e-04,  1.36341288e-04],
   [ 2.67631025e-04,  2.15149150e-04],
   [ 2.91718607e-04,  2.33943792e-04]], dtype=float32))
```

Any idea what's going on ?

Comment: *"I still get a Nx2 array so I don't think these are the left and right channel..."*  Why not?  Call the array `data`; then `data[:, 0]` and `data[:, 1]` are the two audio channels.  That is, each column holds a channel.

Comment: But then why do I still get the 2 dimensions when I render the audio data as mono ?

Comment: How do you "render the audio data as mono"?  I don't know what that means.  You say you converted the data to mono--show the code that you used.

Comment: In the DAW that I use (reaper) you can choose to write the wav file as mono or as stereo, this is what I did. So I can't show you the code, since I didn't programm this part myself. EDIT : it turns out, selecting mono in the DAW still renders as stereo somehow, so I have to fiddle more with it to try to test again.

Answer (score 1):

The last dimension is the number of channels. 2 means that you have a stereo wav file as input.